# Fastest programming language for computing large numbers?

Tags: math, numbers, largenumber

If I wanted to compute numbers with hundreds of millions of digits (positive integers), which programming language would be best suited for that?

Currently I'm using python and the script is running and it was easy to code, but I have concerns for its speed.

I don't really know much about assembly at all so while it MAY be the fastest, I would rather not use that. Is C the best choice here?

The specific operations I have to use are *, -, % (mod), exponentiation, equality testing (if statements), and basic looping and some sort of outputting capability (console output for example).

Many thanks.

Comment: can you provide some more context? What are you trying to do? What OS are you on? What kind of *speed* are you looking for?

Comment: Ah, I apologize for not specifying the OS. Currently I'm using Windows 7 and as for what I'm trying to do, I'm just running some very large numbers through some algorithm for fun =D

Comment: *compute numbers with hundreds of millions of digits* sounds a little bit tricky. Addition, substraction and modulo... maybe. But multiplication? That's going to be **slow**, no matter what programming language...

Comment: You might want to try the GMP library, written in C, it does what you want yet you will not end up creating your own implementation: http://gmplib.org/

Comment: Spend your time on algorithmic improvements, rather than language hopping.

Comment: As mentioned below, use gmpy. It provides acess to the GMP library. For the size numbers you are using, the overhead of Python will be very small. And it will be easy to modify your program to use gmpy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) with plain C, but note that a lot of dynamic languages use it for arbitrary precision numbers, python too. You might not gain much by using C.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this part? This computation may run for days or weeks so any speed boost I can get is not negligible. How much of an overhead do you think python is over just writing it in plain C?

Comment: depends on what you're trying to do... if 90% of the time is spent in GMP, and 10% Python then you won't gain much.. if there's a lot of control structure, manipulating containers etc then it might worth it.

Comment: @Mark Byers: uhm no.. with hunders of millions of digits that's definitely highly unrealistic. python is just a thin wrapper for those calculations.

Comment: @Mark - normally I wouldn't doubt that, but in this case, a lot of time will be spent in the GMP code for each basic math operation - e.g. multiplying two hundreds-of-millions-of-digits will take a fair amount of time. In comparison, the time spent in the Python-coded algorithm could easily be trivial.

Comment: @yi_H: uhm no.. Python uses it own implementation for arbitrary precision numbers. The gmpy module [ http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/ ] provides a wrapper for the GMP library. For numbers in millions of digits, gmpy is much faster. Quick test: raising a million digit number to the 100th power takes about 4 seconds on a fast 64-bit machine. Multiplying two 100 million digits numbers takes about 3 seconds. The overhead for using Python is extremely low. Disclaimer: I maintain gmpy.

Comment: @casevh: Thank you! Didn't know that. What's the reason for python's own implementation? Is it faster for not-so-big ints?

Comment: @yi_H - seems unlikely. I'm pretty sure that GMP uses several different algorithms for some operations, choosing the one it expects to be fastest in each case. Although there's an overhead for choosing, I doubt that's a big deal. Python and GMP were first developed around the same time, but Python was inspired by the earlier ABC, which also had big integers - maybe some of the code was "inspired" by ABC too, so it could just be history and the hassle of swapping over. But I wonder about the criticism (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multi-Precision_Library) of GMPs support of Visual Studio.

Comment: So to be clear, GMPy is just a (thin) wrapper for using GMP in python. And it would actually be very very slightly faster if I just implemented my algorithm in C? Is there any advantage (eg ease of use) that GMPy has that GMP does not? I'm not very familiar with Python and I'm trying to decide which language is best for my project.

Answer (score 2):

GMP library with C/C++.

http://gmplib.org/

Answer (score 0):

Here is your resource to read up on.  This refutes the argument that C is fastest, unless you use the C99 restrict feature.  If anything C++ is faster than C.  It really comes down to the compiler understanding when two separate but sequential operations 'read' reference the same memory location. This allows the compiler to reorder the operations for optimization.  It appears Fortran is best at doing this.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing

Also you can see here that Fortran blows C++ away at the Mandelbrot routine.  But when it comes to text manipulation C++ appears to be tops.

http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/fortran.php

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: All that link shows is that poorly written C++ code performs poorly using a *specific* compiler, it doesn't mean at all that C++ or Fortran is inherently faster than the other.

Comment: @MooingDuck and dreamlax:  I'm guessing you two probably understand compilers better that I do so feel free to contribute to the discussion.  Programming is nothing more than a hobby of mine ..., a hobby I've spent far too much time with.